# Recurrence: T(n) = (2+1/log n)T(n/2)

Tags: algorithm, big-o, recurrence

I have to solve this recurrence relation with tree method, because Master theorem does not apply.

*T(n) = (2+1/log n) T(n/2)*

Answer (score 2):

After a some thoughts I can not come up with an exact solution. Master's theorem does not work here and unrolling the tree has not gave me anything reasonable. So I will just estimate the complexity in the following way.

For any reasonably big `n` you can estimate `0 < 1/log n < 1`. So you can get:

```
T1(n) = 2 * T1(n/2)
T2(n) = 3 * T2(n/2)
```

and `O(T1) < O(T) < O(T2)`. You can find the complexity for both recurrences using [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem). The complexity of `T1` is `O(n)` and of `T2` is `O(n^log2(3))`.

So you can be sure that the complexity of your recurrence is bigger than `O(n)` and less than `O(n^1.58)`, so less than quadratic.